# jQuery Datatables adding 2 columns

Tags: datatables, rendering

I am trying to add two columns with the fllowing code in the ajax that returns the data (Yarja)

```
 public function AllUsersData(Request $request)
    {
       $us = DB::table('users')
            ->join('clients','users.client_id','=','clients.id')
            ->select('users.id as id','users.name as name','users.email as email','clients.companyName as company','users.active','users.operative','users.superAdmin')
            ->get();
       return Datatables::of($us)
       ->addColumn('action', function($pubs){
             $btn = '<div style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></div>';
             return $btn;
        })
       ->addColumn('action2',function($pubs){
            $editBtn = '<div style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></div>';
            return $editBtn;
       })
        ->make(true);           
    }
```

This will enable me to render each column with a link.

My problem is that it is returning the second addColumn wrongly.

Here is what is being returned:

```
"id": "3",
"name": "Jim Elliott",
"email": "webmaster@tdbcomputing.com",
"company": "Associated Locks Ltd",
"active": "1",
"operative": "0",
"superAdmin": "1",
"action": "<div style=\"float:right\"><i class=\"fas fa-book\"></i></div>",
"action2": "&lt;div style=&quot;float:right&quot;&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;fas fa-edit&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
```

As you can see the last column is not return like it's previous column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have solved it. I was thinking backwards! The answer is to return the data differently and then reder it. I was making it too complicated!

My ajax call (Laravel using Yarja) is now

```
 public function AllUsersData(Request $request)
    {
       $us = DB::table('users')
            ->join('clients','users.client_id','=','clients.id')
            ->select('users.id as id','users.name as name','users.email as email','clients.companyName as company','users.active','users.operative','users.superAdmin')
            ->get();
       return Datatables::of($us)
       /*->addColumn('action', function($pubs){
             $btn = '<div style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></div>';
             return $btn;
        })
       ->addColumn('action2',function($pubs){
            $editBtn = '<div style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></div>';
            return $editBtn;
       })*/
        ->make(true);

        
    }
```

I got the name of the two URLs for edit and show with:

```
$editR = url('admin/allUsers.edit');
$showR = url('admin/allUsers.show');
```

I had to add the admin to the route name and my view now has the two additional columns defined with the parameters as below (in the colDefs):

```
 {
    "targets": 6,
    "data": "id",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return '<a href="{{ $editR }}/' + data + '" title="edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>';
    }
  },
  {
    "targets": 7,
    "data": "id",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return '<a href="{{ $showR }}/' + data + '" title="detail"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>';
    }
  },
```